# Bundle Typescript 3.2.4 for the browser in a single file

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, browserify, systemjs

Originally these where JS files and all was well. But I wanted some simple type checking, so I converted to TypeScript.

What I would like is to compile all the `.ts` files into one `.js` suitable for use in the browser with a simple script tag.

This project does NOT include webpack, so please refrain from webpack related instructions.

I tried this

```
tsc main.ts --module amd --outFile main.js
```

and

```
tsc main.ts --module system --outFile main.js
```

But both seem to require I include a further third party library on the page.

Is there a way I can get all the files concatenated together so everything just works? I tried running the output of the amd built version through the `browserify` command, but no dice.

If this doesn't work I will just go back to `.js` and include with script tags like normal.

---

TLDR: How can I get bundled ts into a single js with no `requirejs` or `systemjs` dependency on the page?

Comment: `--module none` should do it, but it means no modules, really - you can use only dependencies that are accessible via globals.

Comment: @artem that defeats the whole thing. I want to share type info.

Comment: Then you have to use module bundler. Browserify will probably work. But it's the bundler that takes modules compiled to javascript and produces a script that could be loaded with `<script>` tag. With modules, you can't use TypeScript compiler to produce single `.js` file directly.

Comment: @artem ok how can I use browserify for this. I tried and did not have success so far.

Comment: sorry I don't know about browserify, I use webpack for this.